# ASP MVC - Razor Layout always receiving Page's Model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

All my pages in my site's layout inherits from a master layout. Whenever I stick a debug breakpoint in my Layout view, I can see that the layout class's Model is the same Model as the controller passes to its View. My layout files are untyped (no @model declarations except in the page itself)

Also, any "RenderPartials" calls that happen inside this Layout passes this model along to other views.

Is this correct?

This means I can do @Model.SomeProperty in my layout which will work/not work depending on whether I visit a page which has a Model class with a "SomeProperty" property!

An example:

Page.cshtml

```
@model Project.PageModel
Layout = "/Views/Layout/Master.cshtml";
```

Master.cshtml:

```
Html.RenderPartial("../Layout/_Footer", null, null);
```

_Footer.cshtml:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.GetType().ToString())


<div class="blah">    
    ...
</div>
```

Viewing this page outputs "Project.PageModel", even though it has no model declaration, and I am explicitly passing it a NULL model and a NULL ViewDataDictinary. I can then call properties on this model from inside a partial rendered by the master layout.

Comment: "I can see that the layout class's Model is the same Model as the controller passes to its View"

I don't think that you should be able to find a model in the Layout, as long as it is the proper (shared) layout page. The 'Model' should be null.

The rest of your statements about accessing a Model.Property on a Razor view are correct. 

What specifically is the question?

Comment: When you pass a model to a view (i.e `return View(myModel)` the model is added to the `ViewDataDictionary` which is passed along. For example `@Html.Partial("somePartial")` will pass the model to the partial, except when you specify another model (e.g. `@Html.Partial("somePartial", Model.SomeComplexProperty)`

Comment: This is the layout though - I thought Models were passed along to the View, which could then pass that Model over to other partials, but I wouldn't have thought that actual access to that Model would propagate up to the Layout itself (and I've seen a few questions on here asking how to get the page model from layout). Could it be from having my Layouts in a non-standard location? (Views/Layouts instead of Views/Shared)